# Finding ratio of sides in a right angled triangle when its two sides are given

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> The perimeter of a right-angled triangle is 4 times larger than the shortest side.
>
> Find the ratio of other sides.

I tried approaching it this way .
Let's have a right angled triangle $ABC$ (right angled at $B$) and $BC=x$ .Then  $P=5x$ and on adding the three sides $AB+AC=4x$.

But couldn't move after this as how to get ratios.

Comment: Whenever I see a right angled triangle I immediately assume a ratio of 3,4,5 Which often works out. Of course if you have to show your working don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Let the sides be $a,b,c$ such that:
$$\begin{cases}4a=a+b+c \\ a^2+b^2=c^2 \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}9a^2=b^2+2bc+c^2 \\ 9a^2=9c^2-9b^2\end{cases} \Rightarrow 10b^2+2bc-8c^2=0 \Rightarrow \\
5\left(\frac bc\right)^2+\frac bc-4=0 \Rightarrow \frac bc=\frac{-1+9}{10}=\frac45.$$